# Wrong default-directory when inside a tmux session

Tags: shell, find-file, term, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux inside emacs for a long time.
I want to use it to attach to remote (long living) session.
Attaching to sessions works fine but I have some problems in my daily
workflow
because **`find-file` does not work properly inside a tmux session.**

To reproduce my problem:

```
M-x term

pwd
```

if you now do find-file (`C-c C-j` to enter line-mode, than `C-x C-f`) it
will start
at your current location. Change your directory using `cd`, than redo
`find-file`,
everything should look like expected.

Now create a tmux session inside your term

```
tmux new -s test

pwd ;; your current location (1)
```

`find-file` should start from (1)
now `cd` to another directory, do `find-file` and it will still starts at (1)

The reason for that is, that the variable `default-directory` is not
changed, when
changing the directory inside a tmux session.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify you are running tmux inside a term session of emacs not running emacs inside a tmux session?

Comment: Yes, I'm running tmux inside a term session of emacs.

Comment: I've had difficulties with the behavior of `default-directory`, too.  Maybe one of my workarounds will work for you: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/set-a-global-default-directory  Let me know and I can type up a formal answer.

Answer (score 1):

*term* handles the changing of directories by the sub-shell by parsing **ANSI** terminal commands. See the function *term-handle-ansi-terminal-messages*. I can't seem to run tmux inside my term but I suspect the solution is to ensure the PS1 for the shell is correctly emitting the **ANSI** escape codes when the directory is changed. Maybe tmux is squashing those itself?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you get for an error message when you start tmux. Can you give me a hint to check whether emitting the ANSI escape code works properly?

Comment: I don't see an error message, it just scrolls some stuff quickly beforing clearing the screen and reporting [exited]. This may be a result of running in a Termina VM on my Chromebook so it could be something about that setup although tmux runs fine in the terminal.