# Direct emacs that open file from the pwd from shell buffer

Tags: shell, find-file

I use shell mode, often. I use the c-xc-f. Most of the time, the start directory for looking for file, correspond to the PWD of the emacs shell buffer. Can i set that it is always the case/or reset it?

Comment: `shell-dirtrack-mode` ought to be enabled and providing this behaviour by default in `shell` buffers.  Do you have it disabled?

Comment: If it *is* enabled, but not working, see if `M-x shell-resync-dirs` helps (use when the shell buffer is at the shell prompt).

Comment: Failing all of that, see `C-h f shell-directory-tracker` and `C-h i g (emacs)Directory Tracking` and start investigating the related variables -- chances will be that your particular shell output is not being recognised by Emacs, and you'll need to do some tweaking to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the shell to always start from a specific directory, you can use the `shell-mode-hook`.  Code stored in a mode hook is executed after the mode is loaded.

We want to send a command to change the directory once the shell process has started. There isn't a stock function to send commands to a shell process.  However, there's a [great StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286579/emacs-shell-mode-how-to-send-region-to-shell/7053298#7053298) which provides one<sup>1</sup>:

```
(defun sh-send-command (command)
  "Send COMMAND to current shell process.  Create shell process
if none exists."
  (let ((proc (get-process "shell"))
        pbuf)
    (unless proc
      (let ((currbuff (current-buffer)))
        (shell)
        (switch-to-buffer currbuff)
        (setq proc (get-process "shell"))
        ))
    (setq pbuff (process-buffer proc))
    (setq command-and-go (concat command "\n"))
    (with-current-buffer pbuff
      (goto-char (process-mark proc))
      (insert command-and-go)
      (move-marker (process-mark proc) (point))
      )
    (process-send-string proc command-and-go)
    ))
```

This can be used in the `shell-mode-hook` like:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (interactive) (sh-send-command "cd /path/to/start/at")))
```

This creates an [anonymous function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/lambda.html) which calls the shell command `cd` to change directory to the given path.  Note that you'll need to quote a path containing spaces.  To do this, escape the inner quotes using a backslash: `\"`.

If you're interested in setting a default directory across *all* of Emacs, and not just `shell`, you might be interested in this SO question: [set a global default directory](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/set-a-global-default-directory).

---

<sup>1</sup>If you like this function, [give user VitoshKa an upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286579/emacs-shell-mode-how-to-send-region-to-shell/7053298#7053298)!

Comment: Hi. My apolgies. I want that if I change a directory in the shell, and, from the shell, execute open file, that the directory shall be the new directory that the shell is.

Comment: No need to apologize! Thank you for more detail.  I'm confused now, though.  How does the standard behavior differ from what you expect?  Do you want the `find-file` prompt to always match what directory `*shell*` is in?

Comment: Hi Lorem, this is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic!  I'm glad I could help!

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please click the check mark ✓ beneath the up/down vote arrows to accept it.  That gives me points which make me happy! :)