# The elisp function to run the shell command in specific file path

Tags: shell

Personally I need run many shell command in emacs, I find it is not convenient to run a shell engine (eshell) or using it separately (bash), so is there a elisp function (local provide by emacs or any other third-part library) meet my need?

Comment: `M-!` lets you run a shell command in the current directory. If you want something else, please give us more details.

Comment: If using this command I need to move to the directory and then type shell command through `M-!`, how to combine these to one step and not leaving current working buffer.

Comment: Type `cd dir && your command`.

Comment: The `cd dir` seems not smart as well as `find-file` function, is it possible let them work the same?

Comment: You can try running the `cd` elisp function instead, but it changes the current directory globally.

Comment: @choroba: No, Emacs command `cd` does not *"change the current directory globally"*. It simply changes the value of `default-directory` in the current buffer. The value of `default-directory` in other buffers is not affected, and its default value is not affected. `C-h f cd`.

Comment: @Drew: Ok, I just meant it doesn't change it back after running a command.

Comment: @choroba: That's a good clarification, which speaks to the OP request; thx. (`cd`'s purpose is not to invoke a command one-off, but to change the current directory for subsequent interactions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Elisp code advises `shell-command` so that you can input a `default-directory` for the `shell-command` if you call it with numeric prefix argument.

If the prefix argument is negative the original `shell-command` code will be called without prefix argument. You get the output of the shell command in `*Shell Command Output*` buffer in that case.

If the prefix argument is positive the original `shell-command` gets also that prefix argument and the output is send to the current buffer.

If `shell-command` is called non-interactively it works like expected if the first argument is a string. Otherwise the second argument should be the `default-directory` to be used for the shell command and the original arguments of `shell-command` should start at the third third argument of the advised version.

```el
(defun ad-read-default-directory-args (interactive-spec)
  "Read default directory and apply INTERACTIVE-SPEC.
Return a list (DIRECTORY PREFIX-ARG RESULT-OF-INTERACTIVE-SPEC).
The default directory is only read with numeric `current-prefix-arg'."
  (let ((default-directory (or
                (and
                 (numberp current-prefix-arg)
                 (expand-file-name (read-directory-name "Default directory: " nil nil t)))
                default-directory))
    (current-prefix-arg (and (numberp current-prefix-arg)
                 (null (< current-prefix-arg 0))
                 current-prefix-arg)))
    (append
     (list
      current-prefix-arg ;; never a string
      default-directory)
     (advice-eval-interactive-spec interactive-spec))))

(defun ad-read-default-directory-&-call (fun &rest args)
  "Run FUN with ARGS with `default-directory' set to DIRECTORY and PREFIX-ARG.
Only change `default-directory' if the prefix arg is numeric.
Positive prefix args are passed to FUN negative are not."
  (interactive #'ad-read-default-directory-args)
  (if (stringp (car args))
      (apply fun args)
    (let ((default-directory (or (cl-second args) default-directory))
      (current-prefix-arg (cl-first args)))
      (apply fun (nthcdr 2 args)))))

(advice-add 'shell-command :around #'ad-read-default-directory-&-call)
```

Comment: When run `ad-read-default-directory-&-call`, it report `entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep ad-read-default-directory-args)
  call-interactively(ad-read-default-directory-&-call record nil)` error.

Comment: @yuanlai That command is not meant to be run by a user. It is exclusively the advice for `shell-command`. Please use `shell-command` only, maybe with a numerical prefix.

Comment: Something weird, the `shell-command` only execute the shell command and not let me to select the file path.

Comment: @yuanlai Try a numeric prefix argument to select the `default-directory` for `shell-command`. The key sequence is e.g.: `C-- C-1 M-!` Literally: Hold the control key down and press the "minus" key and the "1" key. Afterwards hold the Alt key down and press `:`. The actual number is irrelevant you can also input `-9` if that is easier for you. Please read the answer carefully to understand what the difference between a positive and a negative prefix argument is.

Comment: when I run `C-1 M-!` and then type `ls` shell command, the result paste on my current working buffer.

Comment: @yuanlai Yes, that is expected since the positive prefix argument is forwarded to the original version of `shell-command` (see the [doc for `shell-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html)). Negative prefix arguments are not forwarded to the original `shell-command` and the result is only shown in the minibuffer and not pasted in the current buffer.

Answer (score 11):

From elisp you can set `default-directory` temporarily and then run your shell command:

```
(let ((default-directory "/tmp")) 
    (shell-command "ls"))
```

Comment: Hard coding the file path and shell command might not as my expect, sorry.

Comment: @yuanlai This is not your use-case, yes. But, maybe this answer is helpful for other users that stumble across this question. It *is* the Elisp answer to your question. The string `"/tmp"` is just an example. The general principle of locally binding `default-directory` is of importance. If you study [the code from my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48970/2370) you will see that I also used this technique.

Comment: simple and useful. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I execute all of my python code through the shell within Emacs.  Here is how I do it.

Although it's not clear what specifically you're trying to call, I suspect that if you understand how this code works, you will be able to adapt it to your needs.  Use the built-in Emacs help (`C-h f` and `C-h v`) to learn specifically what various parts of the code do.

## Create a shell in which to send a command to

This function is basically a convenience wrapper around what @amitp has already posted.  It first checks if a `shell` process currently exists, creating one if none does.  It then sends the provided `command` argument to the shell and executes it, along with some repositioning of the cursor.  (Essentially it pastes the `command` into the shell and presses `<RET>`.)

```lisp
    (defun my-sh-send-command (command)
      "Send COMMAND to current shell process.

    Creates new shell process if none exists.

    See URL `https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053298/5065796'"
      (let ((proc (get-process "shell"))
            pbuf)
        (unless proc
          (let ((currbuff (current-buffer)))
            (shell)
            (switch-to-buffer currbuff)
            (setq proc (get-process "shell"))
            ))
        (setq pbuff (process-buffer proc))
        (setq command-and-go (concat command "\n"))
        (with-current-buffer pbuff
          (goto-char (process-mark proc))
          (insert command-and-go)
          (move-marker (process-mark proc) (point))
          )
        (process-send-string proc command-and-go)))
```

## Send a shell command using the currently visited file

I use python, so this function concatenates the current buffer name with a `"python "` prefix and sends it to the shell.  Just change the `"python "` part in the `(concat ...)` statement to whatever you need.

```lisp
    (defun my-buffer-file-to-shell ()
      "Send current buffer file to shell as python call."
      (interactive)
      (my-sh-send-command (concat "python " (buffer-file-name))))
```

In this case, the path is absolute and comes from `buffer-file-name`.  If you need to execute the code in a different directory, you will need to modify the `default-directory`, as @amitp states.  Note that `default-directory` is *buffer local*.  You can read more about setting `default-directory` programmatically [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/set-a-global-default-directory).

## Bind everything to a convenient key

I have a global shell command which runs the `main` project file and is bound to `F7`.  If I want to run the currently visited file with python, I press `S-f7`.

```lisp
    (global-set-key (kbd "<S-f7>") 'my-buffer-file-to-shell)
```