# Setup find-file-at-point to treat tilde as project root

Tags: find-file, javascript, project

A JavaScript project is setup with webpack path resolver like this:

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~': path.resolve(cwd, 'src')
        }
    },
```

This has the effect that a line in `c:/projects/myproject/src/models/User.js`

```
import '~/config/global';
```

will point to `c:/projects/myproject/src/config/global.js`.

Can I setup `find-file-at-point` (or any other interactive function) so that when in `User.js` the point is at the file path `~/config/global.js` and I invoke `f-f-a-p` (or other magic), the `global.js` file is opened?

I.e., can I replace the meaning of `~` on a per-project or global basis?

This is Windows 10 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This custom function finds the file as described by looking for the `src` directory of the file currently being visited and assumes that the directory one above is the `cwd`.

As a consequence it only works if used while visiting a file somewhere inside the `src` directory else it will not find the `cwd`.

```lisp
(defun my-find-file-at-point-with-tilde ()
  "Find the file at point changing tilde to project root."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((current-filename buffer-file-name)
         ;; Get cwd from filename.
         (cwd (car (split-string current-filename "/src/")))
         ;; Get filename at point.
         (filename-at-point (thing-at-point 'filename))
         ;; Replace ~ with src
         (filename-stripped (replace-regexp-in-string "~" "src" filename-at-point))
         ;; Get the filename with cwd and the stripped filename.
         (filename (expand-file-name filename-stripped cwd)))
    (if (file-exists-p filename)
        (find-file filename)
      (user-error "File %s does not exist" filename))))
```

Evaluate the function or add it to your init file and then call it with <kbd>M-x my-find-file-at-point-with-tilde RET</kbd> while point is at `~/config/global.js`.

> *Remark:
>
>   It would be probably better to use something else than the tilde as this is usually reserved for the home directory and might confuse others.*

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project (ffip).

What `~` means does not matter. ffip will try to find file in project root using the file name under cursor.

Example, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50567/202